# How to know / test a supercapacitors really store the energy

Tags: capacitor, energy, charge

If i charge a supercapacitor, how do i know or test this supercapacitors that it really store the energy (like a battery) and doesn't discharge ? Can anyone give some reference or method?

Can i use the multimeter to see whether the supercapacitor have voltage or not?if it has voltage ,then it does charge the energy?

Comment: discharge it, and see the energy come out. Or wait an hour, or day, then discharge it.

Comment: these types of simple questions show no effort to learn by re-search. read the datasheets,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do i know or test this supercapacitors that it really store the energy (like a battery) and doesn't discharge ?

Put a high impedance voltmeter across the super capacitor and plot the reduction of voltage with time. Energy stored is \$\frac{CV^2}{2}\$ so as the voltage dwindles, so does the energy. If V reduces to 90%, Energy has reduced to 81%.

Comment: Can i use the  multimeter to see whether the supercapacitor have voltage or not?

Comment: I mean,separate the supercapacitor from the original circuit,and use the multimeter to measure its voltage?if it has voltage ,then it does charge the energy?

Comment: @ShineSun Charge the super capacitor then disconnect it from the charging circuit and apply a voltmeter. Record volt meter readings every hour or minute and notice the voltage fall over time.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the double layer electric effect, there is a special procedure given by the Mfg to get the rated capacitance.  You may follow that process by that datasheet which may or not conform to the test standards established.

If you dont care about accuracy because at high currents, it is time rate dependent.

It is trivial

C= Ic*dt/dV